# SCCM 2012 Query all software installed minus MS updates

Tags: sql-server, report, sccm

I am trying to put together a Report or Query that will list all the software on the workstations under Add or Remove.

There is a report that comes with SCCM 2012 called "Count all instances of software registered with Add or Remove Programs" 
This does the job, but it lists for all of MS office applications. Rather then just Office 2010 SP1. This report bring up over 115k for Office 2010. So I am assuming it picked up Word, PowerPoint etc..
Just want a report that will show me the count of how many people are using Office 2010, and other application out in the field with the correct name of the applications.

I am not quiet up to par in creating queries as of yet, work in progress. As anyone come up a report that does something like this.

Just tried the report called "Count all inventoried products and versions" ProductName says "Microsoft Windows Operating System" 12.0.7600.16385 count 5771.

Any help on this would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get a list back of all of the software installed on a specific computer?

If so, this query should work.

```
select SCCM.Name0
,CAT.[ProductName0]
,CAT.[ProductVersion0]
,CAT.[Publisher0]
,CAT.[NormalizedName]

FROM v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED as CAT
join v_R_System as SCCM on CAT.ResourceID = SCCM.ResourceID
where SCCM.Name0 like '%' + @SystemName0 + '%'
order by CAT.[ProductVersion0] desc
```

You'll need to setup a variable for @SystemName0 in your report.

Comment: Will need it of All Windows workstations, not servers.

Comment: This report is designed to be used for getting back a full list of software for each single system, as specified within @SystemName0.

Are you wanting a list of every single program installed on all systems, as one combined report?  I am struggling to understand the use of such a report, to be honest.